# RPC Error: "Missing Authentication Token"

Tags: tezos-client, rpc

I run tezos-client rpc list , the error say "message": "Missing Authentication Token" , What can i do fix error! I need help[image]

Comment: Is that the exact command you are using? How did you start your node?

Comment: I command tezos-node --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:port can run rpc interface but I learn to node.js and write code try  interactive  to tezos node rpc

Comment: @Roger please edit your question and include full details of your setup, include any code you have, post the URL you are trying to hit, are you using any other third party services or indexers etc. Posting this error message on its own with no context of any kind, is impossible to debug

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin OK I edit.